# How to get console error (developer tools) on Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, error-handling

I Using LogEntries to get that but It's work on Chrome browser but not work on Internet Explorer.
I need get console error to check javascript's activation. How to get that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use F12 developer tools to check whether it contains some error? whether the LogEntries reference load success? Besides, you could also contact with LogEntries team or check the related document, whether the LogEntries support IE browser?

As a workaround, I suggest you could use Console.log() method log the javascript function activation. Try to use this method in your Javascript function.